# Changing the Target directory in HIVE

Tags: hadoop, hive, bigdata, sqoop, hiveql

I am importing a table from NETEZZA into HIVE. I have explicitly mentioned my target directory in the SQOOP command, but it always takes the default path: **/user/hive/warehouse**

How to change this default path??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In $HIVE_CONF/conf/hive-site.xml you have to put this :

```
<property>
  <name>hive.metastore.warehouse.dir</name>
  <value>your/directory/in/hdfs</value>
</property>
```

And then restart hive.

Comment: No problem, can you validate the answer ? :D

Comment: I think there is a typo in your answer, name should be `hive.metastore.warehouse.dir`